# Wiktionary/MediaWiki Search & Suffix Filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, wiktionary

I'm building an application that will hopefully use Wiktionary words and definitions as a data source. In my queries, I'd like to be able to search for all Wiktionary entries that are similar to user provided terms in either the title or definition, but also have titles ending with a specified suffix (or one of a set of suffixes).

For example, I want to find all Wiktionary entries that contain the words "large dog", like this:
https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=large%20dog

But further filter the results to only contain entries with titles ending with "d". So in that example, "boarhound", "Saint Bernard", and "unleashed" would be returned.

Is this possible with the MediaWiki search API? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK - a similar feature request is [T12808](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T12808).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly possible with ElasticSearch/CirrusSearch, but [disabled for performance reasons](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T90090). You can still use it on your wiki, or [attempt smart search queries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch).

Usually for Wiktionary I use [yanker](https://tools.wmflabs.org/pirsquared/ts_archive/mzmcbride/yanker.py), which can access the page table of the database. Your example (one-letter suffix) would be huge, but for instance [`.*hound$`](https://tools.wmflabs.org/pirsquared/ts_archive/mzmcbride/yanker.py?db=enwiktionary_p&list=pages&category=&page=&pattern=.*hound%24&namespace=0&limit=5000&sort=&wrapper=%241) finds:

`Afghan_hound
Bavarian_mountain_hound
Foxhound
Irish_Wolfhound
Mahound
Otterhound
Russian_Wolfhound
Scottish_Deerhound
Tripehound
basset_hound
bearhound
black_horehound
bloodhound
boarhound
bookhound
boozehound
buckhound
chowhound
coon_hound
coonhound
covert-hound
covert_hound
coverthound
deerhound
double-nosed_andean_tiger_hound
elkhound
foxhound
gazehound
gorehound
grayhound
greyhound
harehound
heckhound
hell-hound
hell_hound
hellhound
hoarhound
horehound
hound
limehound
lyam-hound
minkhound
newshound
nursehound
otterhound
powder_hound
powderhound
publicity-hound
publicity_hound
rock_hound
rockhound
scent_hound
scenthound
shag-hound
sighthound
sleuth-hound
sleuthhound
slot-hound
slowhound
sluthhound
smooth_hound
smoothhound
smuthound
staghound
war_hound
whorehound
wolfhound`

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely helpful.

Comment: Yanker doesn't seem to exist anymore, is there a new URL for this service or a new service that works like it?

Comment: @nightpool not sure; the last time I had to perform such a search, I queried the DB directly on [quarry](https://quarry.wmcloud.org/). Note that the built-in search (CirrusSearch) got better since 2015, so quite often a wildcard search may manage to do the job. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch